# How to respond BottomSheetDialogFragment's outside touch events in Android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I want to prevent dialog dismissing and response touch event behide the dialog when I touch outside of the BottomSheetDialogFragment, so I do like this in my BottomSheetDialogFragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.poi_result_bottom_dialog, container, false);
    this.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return dialogView;
}
```

However, I find if I set 'setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)', my activity under the dialog can't respond touch event when I touch outside of the dialog.

Comment: That's by design! Why would you want it different.

Comment: I‘m new, and I just know this method. Is there any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using a `BottomSheetDialog`. What you want is referred as a Persistent Bottom Sheet. It is well described with instructions at [androidhive.info](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/) by using an embedded `View`, and setting up a `BottomSheetBehavior`.